# how wordpress can un-slug a title

Tags: php, wordpress, url, slug

i still , don't understand , how **wordpress** can understand what is this url refer to :
www.mysite.com/about-me/

they are using no identifier

if they using slug functions so how they can retain story information or in other word , how they change back the slugged title to select from database

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question. I assume the slug is stored in the database as is (i.e. as `about-me`) and WP makes a query to that effect. What about this is unclear?

Comment: The slug is indeed stored in the db, linked to the corresponding post/page.

Comment: no , it doesnt store title in db , better to know wordpress

Answer (score 6):

It processes the "pretty" URL and queries the database with that data. Of course slugs are checked to be unique on creation. Details are in the function `url_to_postid()` in the file `wp-includes/rewrite.php`.

If you want to directly obtain the id from the slug you can query the database:

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_name = '$slug'
```

you might need to check `wp_posts` which is the default name, but it depends on the installation.

Comment: ok now how can i write that function for my project and change post title to post id

Comment: and u r saying that wordpress store slug in its table !?
but i didnt see any slug in the table

Answer (score 0):

*This is just a guess:*

My guess is that they store the titles in a database, and make sure every title is unique. That way, they can do a look-up by title and know which item is coupled to that.